# Analysing Chrome's 'Aw, snap' on android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, crash

Can any kind soul give me any tips on how to go about finding the source of an 'Aw, snap' Chrome browser crash on an Android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2)?

I am developing an HTML5 / Javascript based game and I have managed to get the ADB plugin working but am not getting much useful info out of it.  It's not crashing at the same point in the code so it's possibly a memory / cpu issue but I am unsure on how to get any more useful info regarding the crash. My interweb searches have not turned up anything particularly useful so it would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction, give me some tips.

Can I get a stack trace?  Can I see the device's RAM / CPU usage when the game is being played without jumping back and forward to the task manager?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome://crashes` should give you the information, and it should also let you file a bug report to if they are caught in there.